# Android kernel build flow with GKI introduced from Android 11

Tags: android-source

I'm trying to port Android 11 to my board(odroid-n2) and I'm confused about how I can build an board specific kernel module and ramdisk. Could I get some help about this?

Recently, to solve kernel fragmentation, it seems AOSP is splitting kernel into two different block.
(1) GKI(Generic Kernel Image) 
(2) Vendor specific kernel

For GKI, I think I can use an image from ci.android.com. 
For Vendor specific portion(Related to vendor_boot partition),

1. is there specific flow for this? or something to refer?
2. I'm referring to {android kernel}/common/build.config.db845c for case-study, I don't understand why 'gki_defconfig + db845c_gki.fragment' should be combined to one to generate configruation for kernel build. I think we only build kernel module for vendor specific portion.

*) For android docs, I'm referring to the followings.
https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels
https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/generic-kernel-image

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, with GKI (Generic Kernel Image), generic parts and vendor parts are separated. As of today, that distinction is quite clear: `vmlinux` is GKI and any module (`*.ko`) is vendor. That might change in the future if GKI modules show to be useful. Then there could be GKI (Kernel+Modules) + Vendor Modules.

The whole build process is quite new as well and still evolving with this quite fundamental change to how Android kernels are developed. Historically, device kernels and modules were build in one logical step and compatibility was ensured by the combined build. Now there is a shift towards a world where we can cleanly build the kernel and the modules entirely separate without overlap. It is likely to get much easier in the future to build vendor modules without having to build too much of the GKI kernel at the same time. Yet, the way the build currently works, it is easier to set up as it is.

Android 11 [introduced](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/generic-kernel-image#gki-1_0-compatibility-req) the concept of "compliance" for GKI based kernels. That means a shipped kernel is ABI compatible to the GKI kernel. In theory that means that you could literally swap out the kernel that you have and replace it with a build from ci.android.com. Note, a compatible kernel can have significant (ABI compatible) patches that the GKI does not have. So, while compatible, it might not lead to the same experience.

Android 12 [enables](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/generic-kernel-image#gki2_0-products) devices to be launched with signed boot images containing the GKI kernel. Since the [Kernel<>Module ABI of those kernels is kept stable](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/abi-monitor), this also allows independent updates of GKI kernel and vendor modules.

When you refer to the [db845c build config](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android12-5.10/build.config.db845c), yes, this looks a bit confusing. This is a full blown config and the build indeed produces an (ABI compatible!) kernel and the vendor specific modules. The fragment can be considered a patch to the `gki_defconfig` in the sense that it does not change the core kernel, but enables the required modules.
For the final release, the kernel image from this build will be replaced by the GKI kernel image. But for development, the kernel that comes out of this build is perfectly fine to use.

In practice it helps downstream projects to develop core kernel features and modules at the same time, though changes for modules and kernel need to go into different repositories (db845c being an exception here a reference board).

To somewhat answer your question on how to build the db845c kernel, ci.android.com also provides the build log along with the artifacts to download. For the [android12-5.10 branch](https://ci.android.com/builds/branches/aosp_kernel-common-android12-5.10/grid?) and the target `kernel_db845c`, a recent build can be found [here](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/7300223/kernel_db845c/latest). The `build.log` states at the beginning the instructions to reproduce this:

```
$ BUILD_CONFIG=common/build.config.db845c build/build.sh
```

This is the relevant step based on the general instructions on [source.android.com - building kernels](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels).